# Ruby NET::HTTP Read the header BEFORE the body (without HEAD request)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Net::HTTP with Ruby to crawl an URL.

I don't want to crawl streaming audio such as: http://listen2.openstream.co/334

in fact i only want to crawl Html content, so no pdfs, video, txt..

Right now, I have both open_timeout and read_timeout set to 10, so even if I do crawl these streaming audio pages they will timeout.

```
url = 'http://listen2.openstream.co/334'
path = uri.path

req= Net::HTTP::Get.new(path, {'Accept' => '*/*', 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain; charset=utf-8', 'Connection' => 'keep-alive','Accept-Encoding' => 'Identity'})

uri = Addressable::URI.parse(url)   

resp =  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.inferred_port) do |httpRequest|
    httpRequest.open_timeout = 10
    httpRequest.read_timeout = 10
    #how can I read the headers here before it's streaming the body and then exit b/c the content type is audio?
    httpRequest.request(req)
end
```

However, is there a way to check the header BEFORE I read the body of a http response to see if it's an audio? I want to do so without sending a separate HEAD request.

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with the `HEAD` request which was invented to solve this exact issue?

Comment: You can also try setting the 'Accept' header to 'text/html'. Well-behaved servers should return an HTTP 406 response quickly if the content at the URL is not representable in HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`net/http` supports streaming, you can use this to read the header before the body.

Code example,

```
url = URI('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306082/ruby-nethttp-read-the-header-before-the-body-without-head-request')

Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
  http.request(request) do |response|

    # check headers here, body has not yet been read
    # then call read_body or just body to read the body

    if true  
      response.read_body do |chunk|
        # process body chunks here
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think the OP would like to not read the body (at least in some cases). If you don't read the body, `HTTP` throws an `EOFError`. I'm not sure how to avoid that - in my case, I just caught it and ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

I will add a ruby example later tonight. However, for a quick response. There is a simple trick to do this.

You can use HTTP `Range` header to indicate if which range of bytes you want to receive from the server. Here is an example:

```
curl -XGET http://www.sample-videos.com/audio/mp3/crowd-cheering.mp3 -v -H "Range: bytes=0-1"
```

The above example means the server will return data from 0 to 1 byte range.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not find a way to properly do this in Net::HTTP, and I saw that you're using the `addressable` gem as an external dependency already, here's a solution using the wonderful [http gem](https://github.com/httprb/http):

```
require 'http'

response = HTTP.get('http://listen2.openstream.co/334')
# Here are the headers
puts response.headers

# Everything ok? Start streaming the response
body = response.body
body.stream!

# now just call `readpartial` on the body until it returns `nil`
# or some other break condition is met
```

Sorry if you're required to use Net::HTTP, hopefully someone else will find an answer. A separate `HEAD` request might indeed be the way to go in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a whole host of net related things without using a gem. Just use the `net/http` module.

```
require 'net/http'

url = URI 'http://listen2.openstream.co/334'

Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port){|conn|
  conn.request_get(url){|resp|
    resp.each{|k_header, v_header|
      # process headers
      puts "#{k_header}: #{v_header}"
    }
    #
    # resp.read_body{|body_chunk|
    #   # process body
    # }
  }
}
```

Note: while processing headers, just make sure to check the `content-type` header. For audio related content it would normally contain `audio/mpeg` value.

Hope, it helped.