# Performance concerns about CSRF protection with large file uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, csrf

I am building an application with Ruby on Rails that users can upload large files to the server.

To prevent CSRF, [the client will POST the request with a `token` for CSRF protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern).

For example:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------27677775382905058935599910838

-----------------------------27677775382905058935599910838
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

t8rwe3udcaTwkJ3wqje1JThn
-----------------------------27677775382905058935599910838
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="blank.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif

<BINARY>
-----------------------------27677775382905058935599910838--
```

Unfortunately, the whole request body will be completely transmitted before Rails can verify the `token`. If the file is large, users would wait a long time then finally get a `401 Unauthorized` response.

Is it possible to read request body chunk by chunk or even [body part by body part](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html) so that server can respond with `401 Unauthorized` as soon as it reads the CSRF token?

Comment: there was similar issue, but they are talking about net/http, may be it can help somehow

[net/http partly read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306082/ruby-nethttp-read-the-header-before-the-body-without-head-request)

Comment: What's the use case? It's it fully API-based? If you're doing this within a conventional Rails (web) app perhaps you'll have the same authorization on the form as the endpoint that receives the file... so any user impact would be dramatically minimized?

Comment: It would probably be a lot easier to just send the csrf token as a request header. :)